# Java junit4 orderly test method run

Tags: java, selenium, maven, junit, automated-tests

I want to run the test cases in order. I'm using java(1.8),junit(4.12), junit-jupiter(5.6.2) and maven 3.6.3. Why It isn't execution orderly test method?

```
package com.amazon.test;

import com.amazon.base.BaseWebDriverTest;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class Turna extends BaseWebDriverTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup()  {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.turna.com/");
    }
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void searchTicket() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void selectTicket() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public void rezerveTicket() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

```
Output
3
1
2
```

Comment: What if you use `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test` (and `org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll` instead of `org.junit.BeforeClass` to get rid of JUnit 4 completely)?

Comment: The problem is the usage of JUnit 4 annotation.

Comment: thanks. This issue done. Like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Junit 5 where you can directly make use of @order annotation and assign the order accordingly. If you still want to make use of Junit 4 then please check out the link here - https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-test-order

Comment: That's great Sansli...! Could you please vote and share the answer. It will be helpful for others